# I want to add href link in form error message, and this link is not static

Tags: php, symfony

I want to add href link in form error message, and this link is not static.I`m try more way, but not has pertect way.I need help

**index.html.twig**:

`{% extends ... %}
{% form_theme form 'Form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_errors_layout.html.twig' %}`

**bootstrap_3_horizontal_errors_layout.html.twig**:

```
 {% extends 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
    {% block form_errors -%}
        {% if errors|length > 0 -%}
        {% if form.parent %}<span class="help-block">{% else %}<div class="alert alert-danger">{% endif %}
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {%- for error in errors -%}
                <li>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> {{ error.message }}
                    <a href="{{ route }}">delete</a>
                </li>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </ul>
        {% if form.parent %}</span>{% else %}</div>{% endif %}
        {%- endif %}
    {%- endblock form_errors %}
```

**validator.php**:

```
public function validate($cooperation, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $couponCodeOr400 = $cooperation->getCouponCodeOr400();

    $qb = $this->repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id')
        ->where('c.couponCodeOr400 = :couponCodeOr400')
        ->setParameters(compact('couponCodeOr400'));

    $id = $cooperation->getId();
    if (null !== $id) {
        $qb->andWhere('c.id != :id')->setParameter('id', $id);
    }

    $alreadyId = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

    if ($alreadyId) {
        $this->context->buildViolation(sprintf('coupon %s is already exist', $couponCodeOr400))
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

In controller, I need this id for "route" parameters on twig, How to pass this value back.

**controller**:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CooperationType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $cooperation = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $em->persist($cooperation);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_cooperation_edit', ['id' => $cooperation->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('admin/cooperation/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Hope you has better way add link in form error

Comment: Have you tried embedding the link to error in `validate` ?

Comment: yes, I tried. After add link, the link and html tag are regarded string, origin output

Comment: You can use `raw` filter to encode the HTML.

Comment: This way is perfect! Thank you so much!